# Using Black-Scholes to price a geometric average price call

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus

Sorry if this is the wrong exchange for this question.  It seems to be the most relevant, anyway.

I'm trying to learn and understand the Black-Scholes framework, with a focus on the stochastic differential equation approach (the exam I will be taking focuses on it).  So I set out a challenge for myself.  I'd like to price a special geometric average price call, where the average is taken on $S_0$ and $S_1$.

My intuition is that what I'm "really" trying to price is a European call, where the underlying is the geometric average of the stock price.  I defined a process $G(t)$ by

\begin{equation*}
  G(t) = \left(S_0 S_t\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{equation*}

The intention is to apply Ito's lemma, so I took derivatives:
\begin{align*}
  G_t &= 0 & G_S &= \frac{1}{2}S_0S_t^{-\frac{1}{2}} & G_{SS} = -\frac{1}{4}S_0^{-\frac{3}{2}}.
\end{align*}

After applying Ito's lemma, I end up with the stochastic differential equation
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}G(t)}{G(t)} = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\alpha - \delta - \frac{1}{4}\sigma^2\right) \mathrm{d}t + \sigma \mathrm{d} Z_t \right],
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha$ is the stock's expected rate of return.

So I see that $G(t)$ is a geometric Brownian motion.  But this is where I become deeply confused, since it is a derivative of the stock $S_t$.  So when I do risk-neutral pricing, do I have to assume that $S$ earns the risk-free rate (which amounts to setting $\alpha = r$, in the stochastic differential equation above), or do I assume that G earns the risk-free rate?  Or something else?

My intuition is telling me that once I figure out which rates to use and where, I can just use the Black-Scholes formula for a call to get this claim price done.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 6):

This is not the way to do it. The Black-Scholes argument requires the underlying to be tradable. $S_{t}^{1/2}$ is not tradable.

Instead, recognize that the underlying is still $S_t$ but the pay-off has changed to
$$
(\alpha S_{t}^{1/2} - \beta)_+
$$
for appropriate constants $\alpha,\beta.$ So, the derivation of the BS equation still holds and the boundary condition is different.

To solve the easiest route is risk-neutral expectation.
$$
e^{-rT}E((\alpha S_{T}^{1/2} - \beta)_+
).
$$
To get the distribution of $S_{T}^{1/2}$ get that of $S_T$ which is lognormal and so has lognormal square root.

Comment: I like your Financial Math book!  I just wish it had solutions for the exercises. :-)

Comment: Also, would it be fair to say that my confusion over the risk-free rate/risk-neutral pricing was "due" to the non-tradability of the underlying asset?  I realize this question might be vague.

Comment: the second edition of the book does have solutions! I think indeed your confusion arose from the non-tradability,

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.  I know a lot of "stuff" but it's hard to turn it into a coherent picture.  I will get my hands on 2ed as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 3):

if we forget about $S_0$, you are just trying to price a power option, i.e. an option on $S^\alpha$.

By Ito 
$$
d \log S^\alpha = \alpha d\log S = \alpha (r- q - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) dt + \alpha\sigma dW_t  
$$
This can be rewritten 
$$
d \log S^\alpha = (r-q'-\frac{1}{2}\sigma'^2 ) dt + \sigma' dW_t
$$
If you set

$\sigma' = \alpha \sigma$

$q' = r  -\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\sigma)^2 - \alpha (r- q - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 ) =  (1-\alpha)r - \frac{1}{2}\alpha(\alpha - 1)\sigma^2 + \alpha q$

Then $e^{-rt}S^\alpha_te^{q't}$ is also a martingale and the BS formula applies with the new parameters (the interest rate stays the same but the vol and div yield change).

$$
  E^Q_t[e^{-rT}(S^\alpha_T - K)_+] = C_{BS}(S_t^\alpha,T-t,K,r,q',\sigma') 
$$

Comment: Doesn't it has to be $E^Q_t[e^{-rT}(S^\alpha_T - K)_+] = C_{BS}(S_t^\alpha,T-t,K,r,q',\sigma')$?

Comment: Indeed! I fixed the typo.