# Optimal number of simulations for Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo

I am building a Monte Carlo simulation model for thousands of stocks. I am wondering is there a closed-form formula I can use to determine the optimal or at least minimum number of simulations need to run?

Comment: It depends how accurate you want the results to be. Your code should print out an estimate of accuracy. If the first run is not accurate enough, you can cut the error in half by quadrupling the number of simulations. I.e. it is a $\frac{1}{\sqrt N}$ relationship.

Comment: See this question: 
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22153/how-many-monte-carlo-runs-do-i-need-for-pricing-a-call